# Why does File and Printer Sharing keep turning off in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, home-sharing

I've never had File and Printer Sharing enabled on my Windows 7 Home Premium machine before.

In The Network and Sharing Center > Advanced Settings, if I turn File and Print Sharing on, press OK, and return to the same screen again, it has been turned off.

The Server service is running on this machine.

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Which screen are you using to enable it?

Comment: @Col: The Network and Sharing Center > Advanced Settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cause was that the Server service was **not** started.  Starting it allowed File and Print Sharing to remain on.

Comment: But in your original question, you said that the Server service *was running*.  Was that inaccurate?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a link between network discovery and the file and print sharing, you may be able to solve your issue by enabling both. Also it won't work if you've set your network to be of type public.