# File and printer sharing option keeps disabling itself

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, vlc-media-player, media-server

## Details

I'm using windows 7 home basic SP1 ,and I have couple of courses on my pc ,I wish to watch it  on my iPad vlc media player

Earlier I had achieved this on an Android device ,where I had downloaded an app called **"File servers pro"** and started a "**native dlna server**" on it.

Later, On the streaming tab of iPad Vlc player, my Android device name appeared and I could browse and access video files stored on my Android device.

I wish to do the same with windows 7

## Main question

Whenever I enable "File and printer sharing" option in "change advanced settings" ,  it keeps disabling itself, every time .

Note:As of now in the network tab of vlc in ipad and vlc in android device I'm able to see

user-PC: user:
UPnP
i can see files in public librarires

## Attempts to solve

1. Check the following services are running

   ->UPnPhost

   ->Function Discovery Resource publication

   ->SSDP discovery
   as suggested  [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rapuTG2U6do) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/326227/why-does-file-and-printer-sharing-keep-turning-off-in-windows-7)
2. Tried disabling Kaspersky internet security and windows firewall completely
3. Tried disabling only kaspersky internet security and enabling windows firewall with default setting [as suggested here](https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/network-discovery-and-file-printer-sharing-reverting-to-off-390782/)
4. Tried enabling file sharing option in "Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall\Allowed Programs"
5. Tried method mentioned in accepted answer here- [Force turn on file and printer sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/1222471/force-turn-on-file-and-printer-sharing)

Nothing seems to work, please help me out